# Does Kotlin break the rule of encapsulation?

Tags: java, kotlin, encapsulation

Variables are used **public** in classes using the **default visibility modifier**. A setter and a getter is created for every member variable, but in Kotlin you do for example:

```
class Person {
    var name: String = "unknown"
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val person = Person()
    person.name = "kevvex"
    println("${person.name}")
}
```

Is this still not breaking the rule of encapsulation due to the getter and setter being applied when using:

```
person.name = "kevvex"
```

If so, how can that be encapsulation? The variable is still public. Declaring it as private would force me to create a setter and getter to get the variable, because of the private visibility modifier.

**I'm comparing to Java that often has member variables as private and a public setter and getter for every member variable**.

Comment: You can change the behaviour of the getter and setter if you want. They're still methods protecting the variable. They're just called in a more convenient way.

Comment: Exposing an internal field of a class, regardless of how its implemented - with a getter or not - is **always breaking encapsulation**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I'm comparing to Java that often has member variables as private and a public setter and getter for every member variable.

This is actually what is happening in this Kotlin code. `name` is not a field (what you call a member variable), it's a property with a private backing field. And if you modify its getter and setter:

```
var name: String
    get() = ...
    set(value: String) { ... }
```

the callers continue using

```
person.name = "kevvex"
```

and don't require recompilation.

I.e. `var name: String = "unknown"` is *exactly* equivalent to Java's

```
private String _name = "unknown";
public String getName() { return _name; }
public void setName(String name) { this._name = name; }
```

and will even be seen from Java like that. So it breaks encapsulation to the same degree Java does.

Comment: Is the way I am changing the variables value correct? So that is how I should do it or not?

Comment: Yes, `person.name = ...` is the Kotlin way to call the setter method.

Answer (score 1):

You can create public variable but only with private setter

```
var name: String = "unknown"
private set
```

Additionaly you can edit how your get or set behaves, just like in Java. There is no problem with encapsulation, Kotlin makes "POJOs" creation much easier by creating "default setters / getters" as public ones